# How to use Group Policy force Office 2007 to save in Office 2003 format?

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

We have a few newer machines running Office 2007, but most of our users are still on Office 2003 (or even older versions) and I've had complaints from those users about receiving documents they can't open.  I've been other places that use Group Policy to set their Office 2007 stations to save in the older format by default, but I can't find where to set this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good article on Technet for how to do this.

Please see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178949.aspx